# Simple Hook-callback fails?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, hook

I have recently been attempting to hook MessageBox as part of a learning course and during this I have developed a hook-callback which is:

```
int WINAPI MessageBoxCallback(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    DWORD dwAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"), "MessageBoxA"); //Grab address of MessageBoxA
    __asm
    {
```

`add dwAddr, 0x5            //Before we continue on-wards we add 5 bytes to the current address to avoid the infinite loop
        jmp dwAddr          //Then finally jump to (MessageBoxA + 0x5)
     }`

}

This is very simple to think about it as we are simply jumping back into MessageBoxA + 0x5 this so I believe has no mistake on its own, I have in-fact even checked if I have forgot to missing bytes but the prologue of the callback is:

mov edi, edi

push ebp

mov ebp esp

That said, I am sure that I have not any mistake for giving back the bytes. If so yet it crashes the program however it shows a message box then crashes after the hook was placed.

I have further checked if the hook was properly placed and it seem perfect I have done all the breakpointing and debugging yet it fails.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBoxA(), depending on the Windows version, does **not** create a stack frame.  So it doesn't restore the ESP register in its epilogue.  But your function does, required to store the `dwAddr` local variable.  So the stack pointer doesn't get restored and the RET instruction in MessageBoxA() pops the wrong return address.  Kaboom.

You'd have to tinker with __declspec(naked) to get your function's prologue to match MessageBoxA's epilogue.  This works on my machine:

```
__declspec(naked)
int WINAPI MessageBoxCallback(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType) {
    __asm {
        push ebp
    }
    static DWORD dwAddr = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"), "MessageBoxA"); //Grab address of MessageBoxA
    __asm
    {
        add dwAddr, 0x5 
        jmp dwAddr
    }
}
```